# Regex to capture pattern with sql

Tags: sql, hive

Given the cell data shown below is of column 'Feed'

```
hdfs//sddad/aa/vv/cc/SR_DC_EF_GF_20181130_20156478907000_484658274168_CO.dat
```

i am trying to use a regex method to only display this value '`SR_DC_EF_GF'`. Currently i am manually doing a regex method by date which i dont feel its dynamic enough. e,g

```
select `regexp_replace([Feed], '_2018.*', '')` from tablename.
```

this will only display and does regex on table that is _20181130. but if i were to have _2019 and _2020, it wont capture and display the whole value. how we can make this regex method dynamic where it can capture other dates?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: The description of the SQL tag you added suggests that you should also add a tag for the specific DBMS you're using, as syntax and functionality varies widely. Please [edit] your post to include that tag, so that we can try to help. It's a waste of both your time and ours if someone writes an answer only to find out it doesn't work on your specific DBMS.

Comment: @KenWhite , i have updated the question, i am using hive. thank you for highlighting this. i will include all this question in my future questions.

Comment: Please note that I've edited your question to properly add the tag for the DBMS you're using. Adding the proper tags means that the question gets in front of the people who monitor that tag and can answer your question. It also helps people in the future who are searching for a problem solution.

Comment: @KenWhite , Thank you. this is my first time though. will note on all the tag to include for future questions.

Comment: Thanks. :-) We try to help new users learn to use the site more effectively. It's nice to meet people who politely accept the information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could look for four digits:

```
select regexp_replace([Feed], '_[0-9]{4}.*', '')
from tablename;
```

However, you are only getting rid of the suffix.  I think you want something like this to extract the piece you are looking for:

```
select regexp_replace([Feed], '^.*([^/0-9]+)_[0-9]{4}.*$', '\1')
from tablename;
```

Comment: Great, since the cell have 4 digits to recognize the pattern , i feel the first answer given works. Thank you